# Using class instance from main form at button click method

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to C# so sorry for this question...
I have following code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test2MailVerteiler
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            string MyXmlFile = "C:/Test/Text.xml";
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Team));
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(MyXmlFile))
            {
                Team team = xs.Deserialize(rd) as Team;
                int n = team.TeamMember.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(team.TeamMember[i].Name);
                }
            }        
        }
        public void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       
        }
        private void btnAddFromClipboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sTextClipboard;
            sTextClipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
            //HOW TO USE TEAM HERE      
        }

    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Team
    {
        private TeamTeamMember[] teamMemberField;
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TeamMember")]
        public TeamTeamMember[] TeamMember
        {
            get{ return this.teamMemberField; }
            set{ this.teamMemberField = value; }
        }
    }

    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class TeamTeamMember
    {
        private string nameField;
        private string mailAddressField;
        private string searchNameField;
        private string altSearchNameField;

        public string Name
        {
            get{ return this.nameField; }
            set{ this.nameField = value; }
        }

        public string MailAddress
        {
            get { return this.mailAddressField; }
            set{ this.mailAddressField = value; }
        }

        public string SearchName
        {
            get { return this.searchNameField; }
            set { this.searchNameField = value; }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string AltSearchName
        {
            get { return this.altSearchNameField; }
            set { this.altSearchNameField = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The class `Team` is created automatically from an XML file, the instance `team` is then created when reading the XML and parsing its contents.
This is done in `Form1` class. When I now click on `btnAddFromClipboard` I want to parse the instance team and search for a string in it which I get from clipboard.
But team is not defined in

```
private void btnAddFromClipboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e
```

How can I use the instance `team` created in `Forms1` when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

```
Team team =null;
```

inside form class.
Then change the statement in the form constructor
From `Team team = xs.Deserialize(rd) as Team;` to:

```
team = xs.Deserialize(rd) as Team;
```